# using beautifulsoup to find links inside header tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect all links that lie within all of the  tags on a page and do that for 125 pages. I've created the following loop but it doesn't pick up any of the links but it also doesn't give me any error messages.

```
for i in xrange(125,1,-1):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.freedomworks.org/issue/budget-spending?page={}".format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    snippet = soup.find_all('h3')
    with io.open('FWurl.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
        for link in snippet.find_all('a'):
            fulllink = link.get('href')
            logfile.write(fulllink + "\n")
```

I think this is exactly what BeautifulSoup was built for but I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that doing `snippet.find_all` throws an exception -- `snippet` is apparently a `ResultSet` object, and you need to iterate through it in order to actually access each individual h3 element.

I was able to retrieve the data you were looking for after modifying your file to:

```
with io.open('FWurl.txt', 'a', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    for i in xrange(125, 1, -1):
        page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.freedomworks.org/issue/budget-spending?page={}".format(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        snippet = soup.find_all('h3')

        for h3 in snippet:
            for link in h3.find_all('a'):
                logfile.write(link.get('href') + "\n")
```

Note: I wasn't certain if there'd be more than one 'a' tag per 'h3', so I iterated through `h3.find_all('a')` just to be safe. If there's ever only one `a` per `h3`, you could probably make the code more efficient by just grabbing the first element if it exists.